# Is there convenient way to put React-based plugin into PHP-generated site?

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, webpack

I've done simple plugin in React.js, it's simple page builder with MaterialUI components and some other vendors. How can I "extract" it to put to Symfony SSR page? I want to render whole form on server (fields such as name, domain, etc.), and then put React-based page builder (most likely as `<div id="root"></div>`) as one of the fields and let React do the rest. Then, on form submit I want to read plugin's output (page builder generates json) and send all data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You Have the Bundle it as a wrapper and call that package like this.

```
<script src="your Js Path"></script>
```

Comment: Sure I know, tell me please how to prepare this package to be completely indepedent